# Testing Asynchronous Mongoose Static Method with Jasmine

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jasmine

I'm working on a Node.JS game project using Mongoose for my models and Jasmine for testing. Each game has its own mongodb document which contains a list of the players and the regions used within the map. One of my Mongoose schema needs a static method that searches for a game with available slots. If no games are available, it will create a new game and return it. If there is a game with slots available, it will return that game. The following is the method I've setup for this:

```
GameSchema.statics.get_empty_game = function(callback){

    //get all games
    this.find({players: {$exists: true}, $where:'this.players.length<4'}, function(err, games){

        if(err) throw err;

        //if there are no games present
        if(games.length == 0){

            //get all the regions
            Region.find({}, function(err, regions){

                if(err) throw err;

                var regions_docs = [];

                //compile region ids in to array of documents
                for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
                    regions_docs.push({_id:regions[i]._id, svg_string: regions[i].svg_string});
                }

                //greate new game with region ids
                var game = new this({
                    regions: regions_docs,
                });

                //return game
                console.log("created new game", game._id);
                return callback(game);

            });

        }else{

            console.log("found game with open slots ", game[0]._id);
            return callback(game[0]);

        }
    });
}
```

This is the test I've set up for seeing if the method will produce a game when there are no games within the DB:

```
describe("get_empty_game()", function(){

    beforeAll(function(){
        Game.remove(function(err, res){
            if(err) throw err;
        });
    });

    it("gets game", function(done){

        var empty_game = "";

        Game.get_empty_game(function(res){
            empty_game = res;
        });

        console.log("empty game: ", empty_game);

        expect(empty_game._id).toBeDefined();
        expect(empty_game).not.toBe("");

        done();

    });
});
```

For some reason this totally falls over in the testing. This is the response:

```
Started
.empty game:  
F

Failures:
1) Game model get_empty_game() gets game
  Message:
    Expected undefined to be defined.
  Stack:
    Error: Expected undefined to be defined.
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/risk/spec/game-spec.js:40:27)
  Message:
    Expected '' not to be ''.
  Stack:
    Error: Expected '' not to be ''.
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/risk/spec/game-spec.js:41:27)

2 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 0.013 seconds
```

I've tried all sorts of async stuff with Jasmine but I usually end up getting an async timeout error. I'm a Jasmine noobie so I guess it's down to inexperience but even after scanning every relevant StackoverFlow post and the Jasmine/Mongoose docs I still can't seem to figure it out. I hope this isn't too vague, if you need to know anything in more detail let me know.

EDIT #1: jasmine errors in response to Vaterrenanburg:

```
Failures:
1) Game model get_empty_game() gets new game when NO games are present in collection with less than four players
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)

2 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 5.02 seconds
```

EDIT #2:
when console.log is used here, it is displayed in the terminal

```
GameSchema.statics.get_empty_game = function(callback){

console.log("hello");

//get all games
this.find({players: {$exists: true}, $where:'this.players.length<4'}, function(err, games){

    if(err) return callback(err);
```

But when it's placed here, it doesn't appear:

```
GameSchema.statics.get_empty_game = function(callback){

//get all games
this.find({players: {$exists: true}, $where:'this.players.length<4'}, function(err, games){

    console.log("hello");

    if(err) return callback(err);
```

EDIT #3
Still not working after trying the $lt indexing but I've found something else interesting. When running the following:

```
this.find({}, function(err, games){
    if(err) return callback(err);

    console.log("games:", games);
    return callback(games);
});
```

I still get the undefined errors despite it being a straightforward query that shouldn't take too long to execute and should return at least an empty array. Could it be something to do with a Jasmine config?

Comment: Could you please also include the definition of the GameSchema? It might be what's affecting your query performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your assertions in the callback function, like this:

```
    it("gets game", function(done){

        Game.get_empty_game(function(empty_game){

            console.log("empty game: ", empty_game);

            expect(empty_game._id).toBeDefined();
            expect(empty_game).not.toBe("");

            done();
        });
    });
```

That way, you're testing *after* the `get_empty_game` method has finished.

**UPDATE**

In response to your new error, try converting all of the `if(err) throw err;` statements in your static schema method to `if(err) return callback(err);`, that way the callback always gets executed.

Also, I noticed another small error in your code: in the last `else` block, you should be using the `games` variable rather than `game`.

```
    }else{

        console.log("found game with open slots ", games[0]._id);
        return callback(games[0]);

    }
```

**UPDATE #2**

It seems that your mongoose query is taking too long to execute. The `$where` piece runs arbitrary javascript, so there is no way it can take advantage of any indexing. This could potentially be what is causing your query to run so slowly. Try changing it to this, and see if your test completes in time:

```
this.find({players: {$exists: true}, 'players.length':{$lt: 4}}, function(err, games){
```

Comment: I've tried this but I get an Async timeout error:
    Failures:
    1) Game model get_empty_game() gets new game when NO games are present in collection with less than four players
      Message:
        Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout      specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
      Stack:
        Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)

    2 specs, 1 failure
    Finished in 5.02 seconds

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to StackOveflow, I've put the error in my OP.

Comment: In response to your update, I've tried your changes but I still get the first error. Also, nice catch on that typo. I've discovered something that might be noteworthy, you can find it in my OP. How do you write out code in a comment by the way?

Comment: You can surround text in your comment with backticks (`) to format it as code.

Comment: Nope, I get the same 'undefined' errors. I'll give up on putting code in the comments so I've put another update in the OP